# tk improper instalation

Tags: software-installation, gtk, tcl

I have installed tk and tcl through

```
sudo apt-get install tk tcl
```

and have the latest version of both.
However, when I go to run wish, I get the following error:

```
application-specific initialization failed: Can't find a usable tk.tcl in the following directories: 
    /usr/local/lib/tcl8.6/tk8.6 /usr/local/lib/tk8.6 /usr/lib/tk8.6 /usr/lib/tk8.6 /lib/tk8.6 /usr/library



This probably means that tk wasn't installed properly.
```

When I run tclsh, I get no error.
When I go to run the program I installed tk and tcl for, I get the following error:

```
/usr/local/bin/trans: 32: exec: /usr/local/bin/wish8.4: not found
```

I have tried looking online, but I can't find a fix.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install tk tcl` installs stuff in `/usr` - if you have a competing tcl/tk installation in `/usr/local` that is going to confusing things (in particular, your `PATH` likely prioritizes `wish` / `tclsh` binaries in `/usr/local/bin` over the "system supplied" ones in `/usr/bin`

Comment: I don't know about the installation error, and I don't want to give you bad advice. However the script fails because you installed `wish8.6`. If you can edit that `trans` file, try changing wish8.4 to wish8.6 (and hope the script still works), or go to https://tcl.tk/software/tcltk/download.html and download the source packages for tcl 8.4 and tk 8.4 and build them -- it's not that hard to do.